# Raw HTML vs. DOM scraping in python using mechanize and beautiful soup

Tags: python, dom, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am attempting to write a program that, as an example, will scrape the top price off of this web page:

http://www.kayak.com/#/flights/JFK-PAR/2012-06-01/2012-07-01/1adults

First, I am easily able to retrieve the HTML by doing the following:

```
from urllib import urlopen 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize

webpage = 'http://www.kayak.com/#/flights/JFK-PAR/2012-06-01/2012-07-01/1adults'
br = mechanize.Browser()
data = br.open(webpage).get_data()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print soup
```

However, the raw HTML does not contain the price. The browser does...it's thing (clarification here might help me also)...and retrieves the price from elsewhere while it constructs the DOM tree.

I was led to believe that mechanize would act just like my browser and return the DOM tree, which I am also led to believe is what I see when I look at, for example, Chrome's Developer Tools view of the page (if I'm incorrect about this, how do I go about getting whatever that price information is stored in?) Is there something that I need to tell mechanize to do in order to see the DOM tree?

Once I can get the DOM tree into python, everything else I need to do should be a snap. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question because in the years since asking this I have learned a lot. Today I would use Selenium Webdriver to do this job. Selenium is exactly the tool I was looking for back in 2012 for this type of web scraping project.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Answer (score 3):

Mechanize and Beautiful soup are un-beatable tools web-scraping in python.

But you need to understand what is meant for what:

`Mechanize` : It mimics the browser functionality on a webpage.

`BeautifulSoup` : HTML parser, works well even when HTML is not well-formed.

Your problem seems to be `javascript`. The price is getting populated via an ajax call using `javascript`. `Mechanize`, however, does not do javascript, so any content that results from javascript will remain invisible to mechanize.

Take a look at this : http://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey/tree/master

This does a wrapper on mechanize and Beautiful soup with js execution.

Comment: These days any libxml2 based parser will beat beautiful soup and there are lots of them.

Comment: Really ? Any links to any such use-case ?

Comment: From my usage, I think lxml > beautifulsoup.  Just a personal opinion.  It's definitely one of the faster ones.

Comment: I found BeautifulSoup everywhere where I looked.